# How to make a PHP MySQL search by clicking on part of a country map image

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am making a search functionality of a website wherein there is an image of an australian map divided into different provinces. When the user clicks on the particular province, it should display the vehicles available in that area. I am not familiar with the most appropriate technique by which this could be accomplished.

Any ideas

Comment: You describe this as a search, but it might be better to think of it as filtering, and with that in mind, are there other filters on this page which have to be picked up? (eg a drop list of types trucks, suvs, compacts etc) -- if yes then maybe stipulate that.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to use an HTML Image Map and have each region on the image map link to a page, like: `region.php?regionId=5`

Take a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

There are several free tools which can help you draw the regions on the map, which will generate the HTML for you.

Comment: Could you name a good free tool which could be used for this purpose, as I have only been able to get a straight line of the particular region. Although the actual area is not exactly a straight line

Comment: Yoosuf, honestly, it's been quite a while since I've used one.  This seems to be a decent one (although pretty old, but it should still work fine): http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/XMap/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use SVG format for the map. Nowadays it is supported in all modern browsers. That way you can draw provinces in exact forms and even scale them if necessary. Each province can be drawn as a single SVG-path.

One of the features [SVG supports is scripting](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/script.html) and events, including clicks. Apart from this, as usual, all logic can be "passed" into JavaScript event handlers from PHP page generator, so you'll then get AJAX requests with proper parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image map in dreamweaver.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c15a.html

or use an online one such as this.

http://www.image-maps.com/

you can then use the href tag to pass in variables to a php page

href="map.php?regionID=5"